# How to print a Locust response (JSONDecodeError)

Tags: python, flask, locust

I have a flask app which looks like the following:
(note I have simplified it for the sake of this question)

```
@app.route("/app/ent/", methods=['POST'])
def methodpost():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    msg = req_data['msg']
    output = jsonify(msg=msg)
    return output
```

then for this, I have a locust file that looks like this:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, between


class MyClass(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def send_post(self):
        self.client.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        response = self.client.post("/app/ent/", json=
        {
            "msg": "test mesg example"
        })

        #temp
        json_response_dict = response.json()
        msg = json_response_dict['msg']
        print("Post nessage returned is " + msg)



class MyTest(HttpLocust):
    task_set = MyClass
    wait_time = between(0.5, 3.0)
    host = "http://localhost:5000"
```

I start locust as follows:

> locust -f locust_myExample.py

Then when I run it using UI, I get following error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any idea **how I can print the "msg"** that is returned by the flask app?

However, just to make sure it works, when I do manual test using cURL, it returns "msg"

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"msg":"test mesg example"}' \
  http://localhost:5000/app/ent
```

> test mesg example

Comment: Error message is quite self-explanatory here I think: You have not defined `response` variable anywhere.

Comment: You probably missed the line `response = self.client.post("/app.....`.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I did what you said and now I get another error. I will update my question.

Comment: Are you sure locust didnt just get an empty respone (for some reason)? Because your new error message is exactly what would happen if it did...

Comment: @Cyberwiz - when using cURL, it returns 'msg'

Comment: @narendra-choudhary - I fixed it. Thank you for your initial help.

Comment: @Saffik If you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. I'm guessing it was that the response was not json?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

The response returned was not json and when finally it came back as JSON, it works.
This line was missing:

```
output = jsonify(msg=msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use str(response.json())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPRO.png)

Comment: Please understand https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34276583)